# Safely connecting a preamp powered by a benchtop DC power supply to a power amp

Tags: power-supply, grounding, preamp

I pulled the preamp out of a broken guitar combo amp. The preamp has positive, negative, and ground leads for powering it at +/-25V. I would like to power the preamp with a dual channel benchtop power supply to see if it works. Is there any grounding or safety issue with plugging the DC-powered preamp into a power amp that is powered from an AC outlet?

With nothing connected to any power source, I verified that there is continuity from the preamp chassis all the way to the ground pin of the power amp's plug, so I think everything should be grounded safely. I also verified that the power supply's DC terminals are isolated. So everything seems correct, but I am still learning, so I wanted to double check before proceeding.

Comment: What's the benchtop power supply's make and model?

Comment: It's a Topward 6603D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be fine. Just make sure that:

1. You select a sensible current limit at the power supply based on the
   maximum current expected to be drawn by your preamp
2. You connect one the terminal of each output channel together: -25 GND---GND +25. In a benchtop power supply each output channel is isolated from the others.
3. Make sure not no mix up +25V and -25V :)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I feel much better about attempting this now. The power supply has a serial tracking mode that shorts the - master terminal to the + slave terminal, so I shouldn't have to worry about manually connecting them.

Comment: I'm glad that I could be of assistance, please mark the answer as "accepted" if you found the info useful :)

Comment: Test successful! Now I need to build an appropriate power supply.

Comment: Happy to hear that :). Have fun!